# unexpected token else javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

all else statements give an unexpected token error

```
var men = 50;
alert("You are a Spartan warrior about to be fighting in the Trojan War, you get onto             your ship and set sail with a fleet of other ships but your ship breaks away from the others in a horrible storm! You have 50 men on your ship, do not lose more than 40 of them, or else.");
var start = confirm("are you ready to start?");
if (start = true) {
   alert("your platoon of Spartan soldiers is on a ship, headed for Troy");
}
else {
   alert("You failed in your mission and are executed in Sparta the next day (refresh the page)")
};
var hydra  = prompt("you encounter a large hydra on your journey to Troy, do you sail past it, or fight it?(fight or flee?)");
if (hydra = "fight") {
   alert("You kill the Hydra, but it has killed 8 of your men");
};
else {
   alert("You go around the Hydra, but it snatches up 6 of your men and starts to follow your ship!");
};
if (hydra = "fight") {
   men = 42
}
else {
   men = 44; 
};
console.log(men);
```

Answer (score 4):

First thing (not a syntax error, but wrong anyway): Compare using `==` instead of `=`.

Your syntax error is that you're using `;` after the if blocks – remove those.

Comment: You should probably replace `=` with `===` to prevent any unexpected type conversions creeping in. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/359509/111219

Answer (score 2):

The unexpected token error is because you end the else's with `};` but should only be `}`

Comment: To be more accurate, he ends the ifs with them.

Answer (score 0):

replace  `if (start = true)` with  `if (start == true)` instead. And `};` but should only be `}`